Intermittent Connection Timeout Error in Vendor API Call on Go Server
I'm encountering an issue where one of our vendors is receiving a Connection Timeout error when attempting to call our API, while another vendor's requests to a different API on the same server are functioning normally. Here's the error message the vendor is getting:
Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='url.domain.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/pns_call_static?UCID=44ac411e-b545-410f-8b23-70c803d79eb8&PNS=987654321&caller_number=1234567890&caller_iso=IN&timestamp=2024-09-23%2021:17:36.781020&username=KNOW (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd1b5205d10>, 'Connection to url.domain.net timed out.')


GCP Server  :
API Endpoint: /api/pns_call_static
Port: 8090
Web server: Apache
Connection protocol: HTTPS (port 443)
Key Points:
Two vendors are hitting Same API on the different server (AWS, GCP IN).
One vendor's request returns a response within 14 seconds(AWS), while the other vendor cannot connect and receives a connection timeout.
Both APIs are hosted on separate servers under the same environment, with no abnormal server load, network latency, or reverse proxy configurations.
The connection issue occurs during periods when the first vendor's API response time is slightly delayed but still functional.
What We Have Checked:
Server load is normal during the period.
No reverse proxy is used in our current setup.
No abnormalities in network diagnostics or firewall rules have been observed.
API logs show that the requests hitting other endpoints are processing normally.
What could be causing the Connection Timeout for one vendor's API request, while the other API works fine under the same server environment? Could this be related to Apache's configuration, SSL settings, or something else?
Any suggestions on where to investigate further or possible configuration settings to review would be greatly appreciated.
